# How can I extract the value of the 'response' from a request and then use it in subsequent requests as Header in SOAPUI and POSTMAN for rest api

Tags: rest, api, soapui, postman

**The API:**

There is a public API available at https://interviewer-api.herokuapp.com/ that you can use to manage your finances in a very simple way.

The API has 2 endpoints:

/login gives you a token which you need to use in subsequent calls to the API in the Authorization header. Every call returns a new token with some initial transactions and balance.

/balance gives you your current balance along with a currency code.

---

So what I want to do is that I am sending a POST request for 'login' and getting a token as response. Now I want to use this TOKEN in my next request for 'Balance' as a Header.

So is there a way in SOAP UI and POSTMAN by which I can capture the response and then automatically store it as a header for the next requests so that I do not have to manually do it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

- Execute your /login request to get the token
- In the tests sections, do:

  `var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", body.token);`
- Use the above token in /balance requests as header item:

  `Authorization: {{token}}`
- This will make sure all your request have valid token generated on run time.

Comment: yes it works and how to do this SOAPUI? where to write this test?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, /login will send the token in response header so take that response header value and store it as environment variable and use that variable for all subsequent requests.

Token as a response body is bad practice as response body should include only API business logic but your case is to authenticate so it should be a response header or a cookie(correct me if I am wrong).

In postman, if you enable the 'Interceptor' then it will take that cookie by default and use that for all subsequent requests so no need to store that cookie too as a variable.